# Circuitpython can't find port Seeed XIAO nRF52840 Sense

Tags: python, adafruit-circuitpython

I have a Seeed XIAO nRF52840 Sense and it had been working fine with circuit python, but one time when I turned it on, circuit python gave this error message:

```
Couldn't find the device automatically. 
Check the connection (making sure the device is not in bootloader mode) or choose
"Configure interpreter" in the interpreter menu (bottom-right corner of the window)
to select specific port or another interpreter.
```

I downloaded the uf2 file from the seed website and the circuit python website (I tried with both), but when I copied it to the microcontroller, the drive disappeared. When I reset the board, circuit python gave the same error message and when I entered bootloader mode, the uf2 had not copied. I have tried looking for other websites/forums which have covered this but couldn't find anything. I am also confused as to why it happened so suddenly when it had been working fine.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. The reason it was not working was because it had code which was running on startup. To fix this I needed to boot the board in safe mode, by doing a slow double tap on the reset button. When I did this the circuit python drive showed in my files and I could access the board on Thonny, circuitpython.

Comment: Every time I upload the code, then I lose the port. Did you face a similar issue?